# Determine the plane which a disk occupies

Tags: geometry, circles, plane-geometry

I'm an EE and my last specific maths unit was a number of years ago so please forgive any incorrect terminology...

I need to a way to determine the equation of the plane that a 2d circle (disc?) occupies in 3d space.

Thanks, Ben

Comment: With three points on the disk you can identify a plane.

Comment: You have to specify how your disk is given to you. What is the input data? It doesn't work without specifying it.